# Lead RecordType Set in Trigger being changed back to Default RecordType for User

Tags: trigger, workflow, leads, assignment-rules

I have a trigger which based on some criteria updates the leads record type. The record type is successfully updated (has the correct record type ID) and an assignment associates this lead with the correct queue (based on the record type).

The problem is that the record type for the lead, is then updated again back to the users default record type. I have enabled field history on the record type field and the second update appears to be running in the context of the logged in user. I have triple checked all lead triggers and workflow in the org and trawled the debug logs but I can't find a reason why this update is occurring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured this one out myself - hopefully this answer helps someone else. In the lead settings, there is a setting to Override the existing record type with the assignee's default record type. Updating this to keep the existing record type solved the issue for me. See screen below:

[image]